# Is there a way to start the flash player (or program) in full screen through the shortcut target command?

Tags: flash, boot, fullscreen

I am trying to start flash on start up in full screen. Are there any commands that i can execute in the shortcuts target path to tell the program to start in full screen? (Not maximized)

So something like this:

```
c:\program files\program\start.exe -fullscreen
```

Comment: `stage.displayState = "fullScreen";` inside your flash app will do it

Comment: This will only work for local content. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState

Comment: Are we dealing with AS2 or AS3 here?

Comment: I think the OP does not intent to code but just to force fullscreen. I think he's expecting something like "press Alt+Enter to get fullscreen". To my understanding, it's not possible in Flash Player to do something like this. Why don't you try to just zoom using your browser?