# How can I make my Flash movie automatically be fullscreen?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, flash, fullscreen, kiosk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to start the flash player (or program) in full screen through the shortcut target command?](https://superuser.com/questions/247570/is-there-a-way-to-start-the-flash-player-or-program-in-full-screen-through-the)

I have a kiosk.  Its only reason for existence is to show content in a Flash movie, which lives on a webserver.  I don't want to have a keyboard and mouse hanging off the damn thing, so I've uninstalled or disabled everything that can possibly start a dialog in front of my content.

- The machine is running Windows 7.
- I have set the user to auto-login.
- I have set iexplore.exe to be the shell (using the winlogin registry key).
- I pass /k to IE so that it runs in kiosk mode, which is full screen.
- I set the homepage of IE to be the page with my Flash movie.

The last remaining problem is that it seems I need to click on the Flash movie with a mouse to make it full screen.  I don't want that.  I want to be able to just hard-reboot the machine in case of any problem and a few minutes later it's back up and running without any user intervention.

So, how can I do this?  I'm not married to anything in my setup other than Windows.  I don't have a mac and I am not going to install a different OS on the box.  But browser, shell, etc, can all change.  If there is a better container than a browser, great, let's do that then.  Pretty much any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would use autohotkey and the *Run* + *Click* command. Look up the examples, its easy to implement. Start your browser by *Run*, use *Sleep* to wait till loaded and website loaded, double-click on the screen position

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm